# Full database schema update with Hibernate and Grails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is there a way to do a real database schema update (without data loss) with grails and hibernate ? When I launched the project, some properties were not updated and generated errors.

My use case : I want to make my property nullable, but in database no changes have been applied.

code :

```
static constraints = {
    property nullable: true
}
```

Versions :

```
grailsVersion=3.3.11
gormVersion=6.1.12.RELEASE
---
org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}
```

Config :

```
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        url: XX
        username: vagrant
        password: XX
```

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do a real database schema update (without data loss)
> with grails and hibernate ?

Yes.  You can update existing schema without any data loss (assuming you aren't removing tables/columns).  You can do that completely separate from Grails and Hibernate.   If you want Grails and Hibernate involved, you could integrate a tool like flyway or liquibase.  The [Database Migration Plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration) is one way to go about that.

**EDIT:**

> I want to make my property nullable, but in database no changes have
> been applied

If that is the only requirement you can simply express `nullable: true` in your domain class and remove any `not null` constraint on the corresponding column.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the migration plugin.